# How to convert a tibble with list column to a list of dataframes

Tags: r, list, purrr, tibble

I have a `tibble` that looks like this (let's call it `param_table`):

```
+--------+------------------+
| name   | param            |
+--------+------------------+
| apple  | <named list [2]> |
+--------+------------------+
| orange | <named list [2]> |
+--------+------------------+
| pear   | <named list [2]> |
+--------+------------------+
| banana | <named list [2]> |
+--------+------------------+
```

- This tibble is the result of using `map(safely(...)...)` to different fruits with a customized function.
- For example, calling `param_table$param[[1]]` will return the result for apple:

```
$result

+-----+-------+-------+
|     | alpha | beta  |
+-----+-------+-------+
| 1   | 0.1   | 1.1   |
+-----+-------+-------+
| 2   | 0.2   | 1.2   |
+-----+-------+-------+
| 3   | 0.3   | 1.3   |
+-----+-------+-------+
| 4   | 0.4   | 1.4   |
+-----+-------+-------+
| 5   | 0.5   | 1.5   |
+-----+-------+-------+
| ... | ...   | ...   |
+-----+-------+-------+

(There are in total 10,000 rows, skipping the rest here) 

$error
NULL
```

- I am writing a shiny app where I need to directly call the table in `$result` as a dataframe. I can not simply do sth like `as.data.frame(param_table$param[[1]]$result)` because this is manual to individual fruit & not applicable to all fruits.
- Ideally I would want the ending result to look like this: a tibble where the param value for each fruit is a df, instead of a named list that contains `$result` and `error`. In other words, I want to keep the `$result` for each fruit while throwing away `$error`.
- I would like the tibble to look like this

```
+--------+-----------------------+
| name   | param                 |
+--------+-----------------------+
| apple  | <df[,2] [10,000 × 2]> |
+--------+-----------------------+
| orange | <df[,2] [10,000 × 2]> |
+--------+-----------------------+
| pear   | <df[,2] [10,000 × 2]> |
+--------+-----------------------+
| banana | <df[,2] [10,000 × 2]> |
+--------+-----------------------+
```

- If I call `param_table$param[[1]]`, it would return me the result for apple as such:

```
+-----+-------+-------+
|     | alpha | beta  |
+-----+-------+-------+
| 1   | 0.1   | 1.1   |
+-----+-------+-------+
| 2   | 0.2   | 1.2   |
+-----+-------+-------+
| 3   | 0.3   | 1.3   |
+-----+-------+-------+
| 4   | 0.4   | 1.4   |
+-----+-------+-------+
| 5   | 0.5   | 1.5   |
+-----+-------+-------+
| ... | ...   | ...   |
+-----+-------+-------+
```

Should I write a function to make such conversion? Something like:

```
for (i in names){
  as.data.frame(param_table1[[as.numeric(which(names == i))]])
}
```

Much appreciation for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `map` to extract the components you want:

```
param_table %>% 
 mutate(param = map(param, ~.x$result))
```